# Bug Chrome (Webkit): Border-style dashed with border-radius

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm having a problem on chrome (and safari) when i'm trying to create a box with a dashed border and a border radius, the border-width looks tinier.

This bug appears when the border-radius is set to 2px or more.

My code:

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.border {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.radius-1 {
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.radius-2 {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.radius-10 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="border">
    No radius
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-1">
    radius 1px
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-2">
    radius 2px
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-10">
    radius 10px
  </div>
</body>
```

Any idea why and how can I fix this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: [How to report a bug in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `em`:

```
.border {
  border: 0.1em dashed black;
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.border {
  border: 0.1em dashed black;
}

.radius-1 {
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.radius-2 {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.radius-10 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="border">
    No radius
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-1">
    radius 1px
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-2">
    radius 2px
  </div>
  <div class="border radius-10">
    radius 10px
  </div>
</body>
```